# fscanf returns empty array

Tags: matlab, scanf

I need to read data from a .dat file.  There are no strings in the file, so using fscanf is valid.  Below is the entirety of my code.

```
clear; clc;

file = 'OIL_SAMPLE1.dat';
water = fopen(file,'rt');
waterDataSize = [3 Inf];
format = '%i %d %f\n';

waterData = fscanf(water,format,waterDataSize)

fclose(water);
```

The file is three columns of numbers in the following format.  There are 2151 lines in the .dat file.

```
1 300 .3
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Try `importdata` or `dlmread`

Comment: Nope.  I have no experience with     importdata  or     dlmread and can't get either to work.